# "...and who knew?" or "...,and, who knew..." or "..., and who knew..."?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions, question-mark, parentheticals

> Maybe by joining that religion I'd be able to understand myself, **and
>   who knew?** Maybe I'd find the meaning of life.
>
> Maybe by joining that religion I'd be able to understand myself, **and,
>   who knew,** maybe I'd find the meaning of life.
>
> Maybe by joining that religion I'd be able to understand myself, **and
>   who knew,** maybe I'd find the meaning of life.

What the most grammatical choice? If all of them are, what's the most commonly used?

Comment: One comma before "and" and one after "who knew", and no question mark;  but I can't offer an explanation, that's just my gut reaction.

Comment: shouldn't it be "and *who* **knows**"?

Comment: @user3306356 It's a figure of speech http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Negative_assertions

Comment: @Mari-Lou Fixed.

Comment: *Grammatically*, all three are identical. This is entirely about *punctuation*.

Comment: Are you talking about the future. If so, I'd say: "Maybe by joining that religion I'll be able to understand myself, and, who knows, maybe I'll find the meaning of life."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the wikipedia page provided by Mari-Lou A http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Negative_assertions

It is a rhetorical question, so it needs it's own sentence. Based the example given on the page, (Smoking can lead to lung cancer. Who knew?!), I'd say that the correct way express it would be: 
"Maybe by joining that religion I'd be able to understand myself. And who knew? Maybe I'd find the meaning of life."

That isn't to say that: "Maybe by joining that religion I'd be able to understand myself, and who knew? Maybe I'd find the meaning of life." is incorrect but there definitely needs to be a question mark if you are asking a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 1):

All posters had good points. It definitely should be "who knows", not " who knew". I would keep the comma, and combine the other suggestions thus:
"...to understand myself. And, who knows? Maybe..."